# Fetching json form from jquery form builder

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery formbuilder (http://formbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and want to render the JSON form generated by Formbuilder on my web page.
Here is sample of the JSON generated by Formbuilder:

```
[{
    "type": "date",
    "label": "Date Field",
    "className": "form-control",
    "name": "date-1502794115227"
}, {
    "type": "button",
    "label": "Button",
    "subtype": "button",
    "className": "btn-default btn",
    "name": "button-1502794117421",
    "style": "default"
}]
```

Comment: Ok, you have my permission to use it. What is wrong? Errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

You need add container:

```
var fbEditor = document.getElementById('build-wrap');
```

Create formbuilder

```
var formBuilder = $(fbEditor).formBuilder();
```

create data

```
var data = [{
    "type": "date",
    "label": "Date Field",
    "className": "form-control",
    "name": "date-1502794115227"
}, {
    "type": "button",
    "label": "Button",
    "subtype": "button",
    "className": "btn-default btn",
    "name": "button-1502794117421",
    "style": "default"
}]
```

in the loop set data

```
formBuilder.actions.setData(formData);
```